# Trying to create a Round Robin Arbiter in Verilog

Tags: verilog, xilinx, modelsim, synthesis, register-transfer-level

So I'm trying to get my RR-arbiter to output correct values with a testbench, but while the states transition properly, the output is always set to the default, `16'h0000`. Any ideas why this value won't change?

Here's my design:

```
module RRArbiter(input [15:0]NodeRequests,
                      //input clock,
                      output reg [15:0]ArbiterOut
                      );    

reg[4:0]state;
reg[4:0] next_state;
parameter [4:0]IDLE = 5'b00000,
s_0 = 5'b00001,
s_1 = 5'b00010,
s_2 = 5'b00011,
s_3 = 5'b00100,
s_4 = 5'b00101,
s_5 = 5'b00110,
s_6 = 5'b00111,
s_7 = 5'b01000,
s_8 = 5'b01001,
s_9 = 5'b01010,
s_10 = 5'b01011,
s_11 = 5'b01100,
s_12 = 5'b01101,
s_13 = 5'b01110,
s_14 = 5'b01111,
s_15 = 5'b10000;

//Clock Gen
reg clock;
parameter duty_cycle = 2;
initial 
begin: clock_loop
clock = 0;
forever
<pound>duty_cycle clock = ~clock;
end
initial
<pound>10000 disable clock_loop;

initial begin
state = IDLE;
ArbiterOut = 16'h0000;
end

always @ (posedge clock)
begin
state = next_state;
case(state)

IDLE : begin

casex(NodeRequests)
16'bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx1 : next_state = s_0;
16'bxxxxxxxxxxxxxx1x : next_state = s_1;
16'bxxxxxxxxxxxxx1xx : next_state = s_2;
16'bxxxxxxxxxxxx1xxx : next_state = s_3;
16'bxxxxxxxxxxx1xxxx : next_state = s_4;
16'bxxxxxxxxxx1xxxxx : next_state = s_5;
16'bxxxxxxxxx1xxxxxx : next_state = s_6;
16'bxxxxxxxx1xxxxxxx : next_state = s_7;
16'bxxxxxxx1xxxxxxxx : next_state = s_8;
16'bxxxxxx1xxxxxxxxx : next_state = s_9;
16'bxxxxx1xxxxxxxxxx : next_state = s_10;
16'bxxxx1xxxxxxxxxxx : next_state = s_11;
16'bxxx1xxxxxxxxxxxx : next_state = s_12;
16'bxx1xxxxxxxxxxxxx : next_state = s_13;
16'bx1xxxxxxxxxxxxxx : next_state = s_14;
16'b1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx : next_state = s_15;
default : next_state = IDLE;
endcase
end

s_0   : begin
            ArbiterOut = 16'b0000000000000001;
            next_state = s_1;
            end
s_1   :  begin
            ArbiterOut = 16'b0000000000000010;
            next_state = s_2;
            end
s_2   :  begin
            ArbiterOut = 16'b0000000000000100;
            next_state = s_3;
            end
s_3   :  begin
            ArbiterOut = 16'b0000000000001000;
            next_state = s_4;
            end
s_4   :  begin
            ArbiterOut = 16'b0000000000010000;
            next_state = s_5;
            end
s_5   :  begin
            ArbiterOut = 16'b0000000000100000;
            next_state = s_6;
            end
s_6   :  begin
            ArbiterOut = 16'b0000000001000000;
            next_state = s_7;
            end
s_7   :  begin
            ArbiterOut = 16'b0000000010000000;
            next_state = s_8;
            end
s_8   :  begin
            ArbiterOut = 16'b0000000100000000;
            next_state = s_9;
            end
s_9   :  begin
            ArbiterOut = 16'b0000001000000000;
            next_state = s_10;
            end
s_10  :  begin
            ArbiterOut = 16'b0000010000000000;
            next_state = s_11;
            end
s_11  :  begin
            ArbiterOut = 16'b0000100000000000;
            next_state = s_12;
            end
s_12  :  begin
            ArbiterOut = 16'b0001000000000000;
            next_state = s_13;
            end
s_13  :  begin
            ArbiterOut = 16'b0010000000000000;
            next_state = s_14;
            end
s_14  :  begin
            ArbiterOut = 16'b0100000000000000;
            next_state = s_15;
            end
s_15  :  begin
            ArbiterOut = 16'b1000000000000000;
            next_state = s_0;
            end

default  : begin
                ArbiterOut = 16'hxxxx;
                state = IDLE;
                end

endcase

end


endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

So your issue is that you're assigning `state = next_state` but `next_state` is never defined!  Since `next_state` is undefined, your `state` goes to default.  In default you assign `state` back to IDLE (hence why in between clocks you see `state` as idle, but you still never assign `next_state`.  Second clock comes and you do the same thing over and over since `next_state` is never defined.  One way to solve this is in the same initial block you assign `state` assign `next_state` to some value.

I assigned `next_state` in the initial block and also in the default case and it worked fine.

[image]